# Import unknown data types into SQLite using Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a huge CSV file (500K rows x 212 cols) that I want to import into an SQLite database in a Java desktop app.  I don't know ahead of time if the column will contain integers, reals, or text.  So I make everything type TEXT to be safe.  This works ok although it makes a 500MB db file.  Next I display the data in a JTable as follows:

```
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
  Object[] row = new Object[numCols];
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " +tableName);
  while (rs.next()) {   //for each row
    for (int i=0; i<numCols; i++) { //for each col
      row[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
    }
    model.addRow(row);
  }
```

This works for the first 158,000 rows but then it runs out of heap memory.  I have the heap set to the max for a 32b system and confirmed the available ram.  I think the problem is that since I stored everything in SQLite as type TEXT, rs.getObject() is probably returning Strings, even though the majority of the columns (as it turns out) are integers, which would take up a whole lot less ram.

Can anyone suggest how to dynamically create SQLite columns in the right data type, and/or dynamically set the JTable column to the right class before running out of ram?

Comment: You know, you don't have to get all the data at once.

Comment: Columns do not have data types; SQLite always uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).